# Creating an XML sitemap generator

Tags: php, xml-sitemap

I want to create a XML sitemap generator. I have a script which creates a sitemap if placed in your directory with other files.

But I want to create a generator which will work with URL. Here what I actually want to create is, get a URL from user, track all web pages from given URL, put them in a XML sitemap format and give back the same XML file to user.

Please help me in this, I am doing this as project work.
Following URLs work in same way:
http://www.xml-sitemaps.com/
http://www.web-site-map.com/

Comment: Do you just want any kind of solution? Or do you want to build it from ground-up? You will need to build some kind of crawler, but you can find libraries doing much of the work for you if you just need it for your own use and/or limited use.

Comment: For anyone still searching on this one, you'll might find these links interesting: [Elmar Hanelhofer's Sitemap](http://www.plop.at/de/php.html) [Joost de Valk's xml-sitemap](https://github.com/jdevalk/XML-Sitemap-PHP-Script)